# Make a PHP echo a link

Tags: php

I am trying to echo the title out as a link, so when it is clicked it will redirect the user to the post.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT title, category FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
foreach($posts as $post)

while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "<h2><a href='post.php?post='.$post->id.>"$list['title']"</a></h2>";
   echo "<p>".$list['category']."</p>";
}  ?>
```

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: `echo '<h2><a href="post.php?post=' .$post->id. '">' . $list['title'] . '</a></h2>';`

Comment: what is wrong with mine as it's not working

Comment: Use error reporting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try to replace your code with this

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
while ($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo '<h2><a href="post.php?post=' . $post[id] . '">' . htmlspecialchars($post['title']) . '</a></h2>';
   echo '<p>' . htmlspecialchars($post['category']) . '</p>';
}  ?>
```

Comment: This worked thank you, however the foreach dosen't work :/

Comment: so `foreach($posts as $post)` what is `$posts` here? its not defined in your code

Comment: Ive added this to the code although its not working, ive messed it up alot  
'<?php $sql = "SELECT title, category FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$posts = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
                foreach($posts as $post) ; ?>'

Comment: Perfect thanks so much:)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<h2><a href='post.php?post='.$post->id.>"$list['title']"</a></h2>";
```

try it like this:

```
 echo "<h2><a href='post.php?post=" . $post->id . "'>". $list["title"] . "</a></h2>";
```